# PyQt5 passing variables to other methods

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making my own GUI and in this GUI I would like for the user to save their current work as a profile. Each time they add a profile, I want to add an action on the menubar so they can open that profile again later on. I am having trouble with connecting the method with the action item inside the menubar.

Here is my code

```
def addFuzzyProfile(self):
    self.fuzzyProfile.append([])
    self.fuzzyProfile[-1] = self.fuzzyInput + self.fuzzyOutput
    self.profiles.append([])
    self.profiles[-1] = QAction('&Testing',self)
    self.profiles[-1].triggered.connect(lambda: self.profileFuzzy(len(self.profiles)-1))
    self.profileMenu.addAction(self.profiles[-1])
    print(len(self.profiles)-1)
```

self.profiles is a 2D list storing an array of ints. 
When a new item is created, a new list is created and that list is filled with the user's data. The trouble arises when I connect the action to the method self.profileFuzzy.

Below is the method profileFuzzy:

```
def profileFuzzy(self, i):
    try:
        print('iiiiii')
        print(i)
        self.fuzzyInput = self.fuzzyProfile[i][0:28]
        self.fuzzyOutput = self.fuzzyProfile[i][28:56]
        self.motorFuzzy()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Now, whenever a new item is added, the i variable in the profileFuzzy method only receives the length of self.profiles at that point. For example, if  len of self.profiles is currently 5, then the 'i' variable in the profileFuzzy will always receive a 5, even though for example the second profile (where 'i' should have been 2) was clicked. This causes my software to only load up the last saved profile instead of the user's choice.

I believe my problem lies within how I connected my self.profiles with the profileFuzzy method. Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
self.profiles[-1].triggered.connect(lambda: self.profileFuzzy(len(self.profiles)-1))
```

into:

```
index = len(self.profiles) - 1
self.profiles[-1].triggered.connect(lambda: self.profileFuzzy(index))
```

To see it clearly, write the original lambda expression as a nested function:

```
def nested_func():
    return self.profileFuzzy(len(self.profiles)-1)
```

So `len(self.profiles)` will be calculated when you call the lambda, not when you created it.

This works because functions introduce new scopes, so every time you enter `addFuzzyProfile` you will get a fresh new `index`. If you want to do this in a `for` loop, you can create a function that returns a lambda:

```
def create_lambda(index):
    return lambda: self.profileFuzzy(index)
```

Then use the function to create lambdas you need.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am having a similar problem which can't be solved by your previous solution:

    for i in range(7):
        self.roisin[i].sigRegionChangeFinished.connect(lambda: self.manageInputChange(i))
   self.roisout[i].sigRegionChangeFinished.connect(lambda: self.manageOutputChange(i))

would make the self.manageInputChange(i) to evaluate to 6 for all of them somehow. I have tried placing a new variable and filling that variable with the value of i but it does not work. Where have I gone wrong again?

Thanks!

Comment: Because each of the lambda you created captured a reference to `i`, and `i` changed in the loop. This did not happened in your original question because a new `index` will be created every time you enter the function, but **only one** `i` will be created in a `for` loop. You can define a function that returns a lambda you need. See my edit.